# how to make "onScroll" stops at a point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, elementor

I want to make a menu which is 6 deg rotated and it will get to 0 deg as it reaches to top as users scrolls and then when it is on top i want to make it stick at top

is it possible to do it in elementor pro?

or with the help of JS CSS Html?

```
windows.onscroll = function () {
    scrollRotate();
};

function scrollRotate() {
    let image = document.getElementById("reload");
    image.style.transform = "rotate(" + window.pageYOffset/10 + "deg)";
}
```

the above code is working fine, but i want to stop scrollRotate function when the reload element reaches to the top.

I want my menu to stick on top as it get to the top with scoll. But at same time i want it to gets from 6 deg rotated to 0deg rotate

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna look into the **Animate on scroll (AOS)** javascript library. It is really handy and quite easy to understand. Instead of creating your own calculations.

[Link](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)